# How to use a delimeter on getline

Tags: c++

I have a file which I am supposed to read each line and store it in struct of arrays, I am reading the file fine but the results are kind mixed because the data is separated by comma, how do I make it read the line separated by commas?

```
struct Data{
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
    std::string c;
}

int main(){
Data cd[100];

std::ifstream inFile;  
std::string data;
inFile.open("data.txt");                 
if(inFile.good()){                       
    while(getline(inFile, data)){ //when I add, ',' right after data nothing shows up 
        std::stringstream ss(data);     
        ss >>cd[0].a >> cd[0].b >> cd[0].c;
        std::cout <<cd[0].a<<std::endl;
    }
}
else{
std::cout << "can't open" << std::endl;
}

inFile.close();    
//close the file
return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: Can you post the contents of data.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon after your `struct` and also always overwriting the first struct in your array of 100 structs during each loop: the easiest solution is to make an index counter, which you will increase with each line.
To split on a user-defined delimiter the C++ standard-library has no pre-made function to do this: either you're using boost or rolling your own solution.

i.e. something like this

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct Data {
  std::string a;
  std::string b;
  std::string c;
};

int main() {
  Data cd[100];
  size_t index = 0;
  std::ifstream inFile;
  std::string data;
  inFile.open("data.txt");
  if (inFile.good()) {
    while (getline(inFile, data)) { //when I add, ',' right after data nothing shows up 
      std::string::size_type startPos = data.find_first_not_of(",", 0); /* skip leading delimiters */
      std::string::size_type endPos = data.find_first_of(",", startPos); /* find first real delimiter */
      cd[index].a = data.substr(startPos, endPos - startPos); /* save substring */
      startPos = data.find_first_not_of(",", endPos); /* find next start position */
      endPos = data.find_first_of(",", startPos); /* find next endPosition */
      cd[index].b = data.substr(startPos, endPos - startPos); /* save substring */
      startPos = data.find_first_not_of(",", endPos); /* find next start position */
      endPos = data.find_first_of(",", startPos); /* find next endPosition */
      cd[index].c = data.substr(startPos, endPos - startPos); /* save substring */
      ++index;
    }
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "can't open" << std::endl;
  }
  inFile.close();
  //close the file
  return 0;
}
```

Limitation: according to your struct, it assumes there are 3 values per line in your file - and according to your array of structs, there should not be more than 100 lines. I would recommend to use a nice [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of an plain old C-style array.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you out in many situations. Open your file and read text line by line into a std::string. Then this useful utility function works great

**Utility.h**

```
#ifndef UTILITY_H
#define UTILITY_H

#include <string>

class Utility {
public:    
    static std::vector<std::string> splitString( const std::string& strStringToSplit, const std::string& strDelimiter, const bool keepEmpty = true );

private:
    Utility(); // Private - Not A Class Object
    Utility( const Utility& c ); // Not Implemented
    Utility& operator=( const Utility& c); // Not Implemented
};

#endif // UTILITY_H
```

**Utility.cpp**

```
#include "Utility.h"

std::vector<std::string> Utility::splitString( const std::string& strStringToSplit, const std::string& strDelimiter, const bool keepEmpty ) {

    std::vector<std::string> vResult;
    if ( strDelimeter.empty() ) {
        vResult.push_back( strStringToSplit );
        return vResult;
    }

    std::string::const_iterator itSubStrStart = strStringToSplit.begin(), itSubStrEnd;
    while ( true ) {
        itSubStrEnd = search( itSubStrStart, strStringToSplit.end(), strDelimiter.begin(), strDelimiter.end() );
        std::string strTemp( itSubStrStart, itSubStrEnd );
        if ( keepEmpty || !strTemp.empty() ) {
            vResult.push_back( strTemp );
        }

        if ( itSubStrEnd == strStringToSplit.end() ) {
            break;
        }

        itSubStrStart = itSubStrEnd + strDelimeter.size();
    }

    return vResult;

} // stringToSplit
```

And to use this in any class or function you simply just include Utility.h

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Utility.h"    

int main() {

    std::string welcome( "Hello,World,How,Are,You,Today,!" );
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    result = Utility::splitString( welcome, std::string( "," ) );

    for ( unsigned u = 0; u < result.size(); u++ ) {
        std::cout << result.at( u ) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And your print out should be:

```
Hello
World
How
Are
You
Today
!
```

Where each word is comma separated without spaces. You can use any character as your defining delimiter either it being a space, colon, semi-colon, hyphen etc. This is a very useful and handy utility function that can be used over and over again in many situations; especially when you are trying to parse either files or strings. Now you have to mind the fact that this will parse strings. You still have to read the file in line by line and store each line into a string, then create a vector of strings that will store the results from this function.

It may not seem intuitive at first to have this function in a class, but I have about a dozen or so useful utility functions for converting strings to upper and lower case, convert a string to different basic data types such as int, floats and even to convert a string of values separated by commas into vec2, vec3 & vec4 objects, where all of these functions are declared as being static in a class that you can not instantiate. It acts as a container or wrapper almost like a namespace. Another words most of my standalone string manipulation functions that would be heavily used I will end up containing them here within this class.

Comment: appreciate this but I'm required to use struct.

Comment: You can take each of the words that are stored in the vector of strings and populate your structs from it making this an intermediate step.

Answer (score 0):

You had replied that you are required to use as structure, well you still can. There are different approaches to this. Now according to your question and the example you have provided your struct has 3 strings and you need arrays of them; let us assume that each line of text has 3 string values separated by a coma. I created a text file named custom.txt and this is its contents:

**custom.txt**

```
Hello,world,how
are,you,today
```

Each line has exactly three words separated by commas with no spaces: Now I'll demonstrate how to use my Utility Function that I showed in my previous answer to split a string after reading in a line of text then to parse it while populating your array of structures.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Utility.h"

struct MyStruct {
    std::string str1;
    std::string str2;
    std::string str3;
}; // MyStruct

void parseLine( std::string& strLine, std::vector<std::string>& results, MyStruct& myStruct ) {
    results = Utility::splitString( strLine, std::string( "," ) );
    myStruct.str1 = results[0];
    myStruct.str2 = results[1];
    myStruct.str3 = results[2];
} // parseLine

bool readLine( std::fstream& in, std::string& line ) {
    if ( in.eof() ) {
        return false;
    }
    std::getline( in, line );
    return true;
} // readLine

int main() {
    std::string filename( "custom.txt" );
    std::string strLine;
    sd::fstream fin;

    fin.open( filename.c_str(), std::ios_base::in ) {
    if ( !fin.is_open() ) {
        std::cout << "Error reading in file " << filename << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> results;
    // Since I only have 2 lines in this file 
    MyStruct myStruct[2];

    int line = 0;
    while ( readLine( fin, strLine ) ) {
        parseLine( strLine, results, myStruct[line] );
        line++;
    }

    std::cout << "Results: " << std::endl;
    for ( unsigned u = 0; u < 2; u++ ) {
        std::cout << myStruct[u].str1 << " " << myStruct[u].str2 << " " << myStruct[u].str3 << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Press any key to quit." << std::endl;
    _getch();

    return 0;
} // main
```

The one thing to be aware about with this particular implementation is that the loops are set according to exactly how many stored values there are in your struct (3 strings) and how many in the array has to match the number of lines in the saved file. This has to be known ahead of time. If you do not know ahead of time how many lines are in the file then I do not think you would be able to use an array since they have to be a constant integral type at compile time. If you was using dynamic memory with pointers on the heap, then you could automate this system without knowing how many elements are on a single line or without knowing how many lines are in a particular file.